# Remove child element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot

I have an AJAX call which provides the data to generate a jQuery plot.  Every time this AJAX call is run, new JSON data comes back and the plot is updated automatically.

In addition to plotting the JSON data, there is also code which creates a button which is appended as a child element using `ConvertOrSave.appendChild(btn);`.  The only problem with this code is that each time an AJAX call is made, a new btn is appended.  There should only ever be a need for one button.

What would be the best way to ensure that the previous button is removed before the new button is added?  Thanks. Here is the code:

```
$("#flotAverageSalePricesCity").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
if (data){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: sURL + "utility/ajaxmuniChart1c",
        type: "POST",
        data: {muni: data[0]},
        dataType: 'json',               
        success: function(json){
            if  (data) {                    
                myWidth =  (document.getElementById('flot_widget').offsetWidth-45)+"px";
                myHeight = (document.getElementById('flot_widget').offsetWidth*.66)+"px";
                document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'block';                 
                document.getElementById('printflotcontainer').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('flotcontainer').style.width = myWidth;
                document.getElementById('flotcontainer').style.height = myHeight;
                var options = {
                    series: {
                        lines: { show: true, fill: false, fillColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)" },
                        points: { show: true, fill: true }
                    }                       
                }; 

                $.plot("#flotcontainer", [json], options);
                myCanvas = $('#flotcontainer').find('canvas.base');       
                flotcontainercanvas = myCanvas.get(0);
                ctx3 = flotcontainercanvas.getContext('2d');
                myLocation = sURL + 'php/saveme.php';
                var cs = new CanvasSaver(myLocation)
                var btn = cs.generateButton('Save', flotcontainercanvas, 'PTS_Chart');                  
                ConvertOrSave.appendChild(btn);
            }
        }
    })
}
})
```

EDIT:  Here is the only element in `ConvertOrSave`:

```
<div id="ConvertOrSave" class="g2">
        <button id="convert">convert</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the classname of `btn` ?

Comment: Can you remove the button addition from the success callback and put it somewhere else (like onload?)?

Comment: @JayHarris there is no classname for `btn`.  It is created only with the code shown here.

Comment: ok now @DanielAttard how many elements are there in `ConvertOrSave` and does it only contain the `btn`?

Comment: @KyleMuir Not sure if I can move the button addition from the success callback to the onload event because there is no plot created until the first success callback.

Comment: @JayHarris I have edited the question to show that `ConvertOrSave` only has a single other button, as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since convertAndSave only have one other element in it, you can avoid appending duplicates by just adding convert and the new button...(if that makes sense)

```
var convert = document.getElementById('convert');
ConvertOrSave.innerHTML = convert + btn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the existing button before adding the new one with:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('convert');
btn && btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/F3Uxa/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the existing button:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('convert');
if (btn != null){
   btn.remove();
}
```

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVCFD/)** this will remove the existing button.
I hope this will help you.